# Using Emoji's in Loops in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I am currently writing a JavaScript that needs to display a multiplication table. However, with the output, there needs to be emojis instead of numbers.
For example, instead of 1 x 2 = 2, it needs to be 1 x 'emoji' 'emoji' = 2.

This is my current JavaScript code:

```
function generate() {
  var input = document.getElementById("value1");
  var value = Number(input.value);

  for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    document.write("<br />" + value + " x " + i + " = " + (value * i));
  }
}
```

I would really appreciate it if anyone could give me pointers as to how I can answer this. Thank you!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find the unicode value of the emoji

https://unicode-table.com/en/1F438/

here you can see that the unicode is `U+1F438`

then use `String.fromCodePoint()` to make JS display it as an actual emoji and repeat it with `String.repeat()`

```
const emojiUnicode = 0x1F438;
let repeatedString;
for(var i = 1; i <= 10; i++){
    repeatedString = String.fromCodePoint(emojiUnicode).repeat(i);
    document.write("<br />" + num1 + " x " + repeatedString + " = " + (num1 * i)); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @CBroe mentioned in their response, you can use the `.repeat()` function of `String`.

Have a look here:
https://codepen.io/Rebouben/pen/MWoGwmM

```
    const frog = String.fromCodePoint(0x1F438);

    var num1 = 3;

    for(var i = 1; i <= 10; i++){
      console.log(num1+" x "+frog.repeat(i)+" = "+(num1 * i)); 
    }
```